# Read values from one observable but switch to another once it (the other one) emits

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

My desired behaviour:

1. Run HTTP request
2. Immediately look up data in async cache
3. If cache has the value before HTTP emits - use cache value.
4. Use HTTP value after it's finally here.
5. If HTTP responds faster than cache - ignore cache.

So basically I would like to kick off two async processes, one of which is supposed to provide a value quickly but if it doesn't - I want to only use the value from a slower observable which takes precedence anyway.

Comment: You're looking for either `combineLatest` or `forkJoin` function. But it depends on how the "_async cache_" you mention is configured. Is it a stream or does it only emit one notification and complete? Could you show what have you tried so far?

Comment: wouldn't `combineLatest` only fire after both observables emit? that's not what I'm looking for. I've tried this:
`const combo$ = cache$.pipe(takeUntil(server$)).pipe(concat(server$))`;
this seems to create two subscriptions to server$.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Both the functions would only emit when both observables have emitted. However with your current implementation the inner observable `server$` will only be triggered after the outer observable (`cache$`) has emitted. So question is to trigger two observables in parallel and utilize the first emission even if the other observable hasn't emitted yet.

Comment: yes, correct! that's how my attempt at solution works

Comment: Tried the following after using `shareReplay(1)` on `server$`: `const combo$ = merge(server$, cache$.pipe(takeUntil(server$)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand from my comments: the question is to trigger two observables in parallel and utilize the first emission even if the other observable hasn't emitted yet.

Normally you could use the [`merge`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge) function for it.

However you have a condition (*"If HTTP responds faster than cache - ignore cache."*) that is not natively fulfilled by the `merge` function nor by any standard RxJS operators.

But it is easy to write custom operators in RxJS from existing operators. For your case you could customize the [`filter`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/filter) operator to suit your needs. See [here](https://netbasal.com/creating-custom-operators-in-rxjs-32f052d69457) for a brief intro on how to write a custom operator.

```js
export const filterLateCache = () => {
  let serverEmitted = false;
  return <T>(source: Observable<T>) => {
    return source.pipe(
      filter((data: any) => {
        if (!!data.server) {
          serverEmitted = true;
          return true;
        } else if (!!data.cache) {
          if (serverEmitted) {
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      })
    );
  };
};
```

As you can see the boolean flags `server` and `cache` in the incoming notification are checked to decide whether the value must be emitted. So you'd need to append the values from the observables with these flags using the [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) operator.

```js
merge(
  server$.pipe(
    map((value) => ({
      server: true,
      value: value,
    }))
  ),
  cache$.pipe(
    map((value) => ({
      cache: true,
      value: value,
    }))
  )
)
  .pipe(filterLateCache())
  .subscribe({
    next: ({ value }) => {       // <-- utilize destructuring to ignore boolean flags
      // handle response here
    },
    error: (error: any) => {
      // handle errors
    }
  });
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-j8zom3?file=index.ts)

Comment: I went with my shareReplay solution in the comment to the question, but this answer is really good, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is worth looking at the `raceWith`: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/raceWith

Basically it would look like:

```
server$.pipe(raceWith(cache$)).subscribe(/*side effect that must be done*/);
```

The thing missing is that it does not fulfill requirement 4.

Comment: Sorry, I have seen my mistake: `raceWith`will then subscribe forever to the observable that emits first, which does not fulfill the requirements.